# Issue with date range on nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I have issues while filtering data from mongodb using nodejs and nextjs.
I am not getting some of the data stored in the database especially if the moment is not this month.

My Routes:

```
module.exports.getFulfullmentByDateRange = (params) => {
    return Fulfillment.find({ createdOn: { $gte: moment(params.dateFrom).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), $lte: moment(params.dateTo).format('YYYY-MM-DD') } }).then(fulfillment => {
        return fulfillment
    })
}
```

This only allows me to filter selected data. What I'm trying to achieve is to get all data using the selected range from the from and to datetime picker.

Comment: can you provide the data, how your storing  that dateField in mongodb?

Comment: This has been resolved. Thank you for your response.